# Do other permissions/ functionality require the view setup and configruation privilege?

Tags: force.com, security, configuration

All of my profiles have the 'view setup and configuration' privilege in production.  The extent of my knowledge on the  `View Setup and Configuration` -is it allows users to view complete Setup menu, without the ability to make changes.

Would other permissions need it? As in would it be required for anything else?

I think this got deployed mistakenly as part of a change set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to the profile list view. add the view setup and config
2. permission to the list view. deselect it, but don't save. you'll get
3. a list of permissions.  go back and add those permissions to the
   list view.

This will let you see the user impact before removing the permission. the way is a little easier than removing and the  this is the painful part or restoring the permissions (not to mention a short service disruption to your users)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many other permissions require this so you might not just want to disable it for every profile. Why not download the Setup Audit Trail and review what got changed when. You can just search the Audit Trail for 'View Setup and Configuration'.